# How to fix JVM argument in Eclipse using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring

I am writing some code to incorporate a Java API in my project. So the API relies on two jar files which are in my local repository and a JVM argument. However, when I run everything with the JVM argument added to the project it throws an error. I believe that in Spring Boot there is another way to handle adding a JVM. That is where I believe the answer to my problem is. If anyone has information on how I can get it working, it would be much appreciated. I have been trying to figure out this issue for weeks.

**JVM Argument:**

```
-Dcom.collation.home="C:\Users\john\dev\sdk"
```

**Error:**

```
      08:33:12.732 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.ResourceEntityResolver - Could not resolve XML entity [classpath:/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.1.xsd] against system root URL
    java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: classpath
        at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:634)
        at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:523)
        at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:470)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.ResourceEntityResolver.resolveEntity(ResourceEntityResolver.java:84)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(EntityResolverWrapper.java:111)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1136)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.resolveDocument(XMLSchemaLoader.java:662)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2694)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2069)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:829)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3058)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:821)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:532)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:77)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:435)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:393)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:337)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:305)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:79)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:67)
        at com.ibm.cdb.api.ApiFactory.loadFromFile(ApiFactory.java:102)
        at com.ibm.cdb.api.ApiFactory.<init>(ApiFactory.java:134)
        at com.ibm.cdb.api.ApiFactory.getInstance(ApiFactory.java:122)
        at com.UPS.TaddmV2.TADDMDataHandler.initAPI(TADDMDataHandler.java:60)
        at com.UPS.TaddmV2.TaddmRunner.main(TaddmRunner.java:19)
    08:33:12.739 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.ResourceEntityResolver - Found XML entity [classpath:/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.1.xsd]: class path resource [org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.1.xsd]
    08:33:12.934 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loaded 3 bean definitions from file [C:\Users\HFB2VZN\dev\sdk\etc\api-setup.xml]
    Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "com.ibm.cdb.secure.server" "write")
        at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:895)
        at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:335)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.setProperty(System.java:862)
        at com.collation.proxy.api.client.ApiConnectionImpl.init(ApiConnectionImpl.java:240)
        at com.ibm.cdb.api.client.ApiConnectionFactory.getApiConnection(ApiConnectionFactory.java:58)
        at com.ibm.cdb.api.ApiFactory.getApiConnection(ApiFactory.java:168)
        at com.John.TaddmV2.TADDMDataHandler.initAPI(TADDMDataHandler.java:60)
        at com.John.TaddmV2.TaddmRunner.main(TaddmRunner.java:19)
```

Comment: I) How did you add the JVM Argument ? II) Spring Boot can create a runnable JAR, in which u can pass the JVM arguments while invoking it. III) In your stack trace , i cant see any spring related logs, and as suggested it seems that you dont have 'write' privileges on the specific machine.

Comment: I think the error message is clear. It seems that you want to set some properties but you don't have WRITE privilege, so please make sure your role can do this such as an administrator.

Comment: @AntJavaDev I have made an edit to the question to include the whole error output. Hope this additional information helps.

Comment: @LHCHIN The thing is it runs and works fine as a regular java class. However, when I add Spring Boot to it, it throws these errors noted above. So I don't believe its as simple as a permissions.

Comment: @AntJavaDev  Also, I added the JVM argument by going to ```Run Configurations``` in Eclipse. I also tried setting in as a path in my windows device "system environment".

Comment: hmm its getting more confused, i am struggling to understand 'when i add Spring Boot to it' as i still cant see any spring boot related logs. Now that you posted the full stack trace it looks like there is dependency chaos going on. If its working as a plain runnable jar, why you need spring ? just to utilize a web service client ? Is this going to be an enterprise app or a microservice ?

Comment: @AntJavaDev Enterprise, I am a designing a web app and need to utilize Spring.